# Fantasy/SF short story about imprisoned artist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I am trying to ID was published, I think, in Asimov's magazine in the early 1980s, though it could possibly be The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, and now I think about it the period might be off slightly... sorry!

As I recall it, the protagonist was imprisoned in a cell and forced to paint artworks. He had a special ability to paint very special artworks with different levels of the paintings revealed by different lighting, viewing angles, something like that (I don't recall 100%). I think he uses one of his paintings against his captor. The story had a sort of "Night Gallery" vibe.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description sounds very much like this [earlier question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185399/looking-for-a-short-story-about-an-artist-and-a-forger)

The answer there was *The Portrait of Baron Negay* by Barry B. Longyear.

An artist is imprisoned to force him to make a portrait using a special technique.  He doesn't know how to use that technique, but a forger imprisoned with him does.  Together the two complete the portrait.

They go it one better, though, in that they make the portrait subversive.  It appears to show the portraited person positively, but it is multilevel and depicts the person as a corrupt criminal hiding behind a veneer of respectability.

The ruse is (of course) discovered and the artist executed.

The forger goes on to make hundreds of copies and distributes them.  The influence of the portrait is so great that is causes the overthrow of the corrupt government.